# WORDPRESS Post Thumbnail -> Link to post

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I've made a custom metabox that if selected makes the post thumbnail the background of the site.

Now I need that this post thumbnail has a link to the post.

> < ?php query_posts ('showposts=5$cat=2');
>                   if (have_posts()) : ?>
>
> ```
>                     if ( has_post_thumbnail() && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dbt_checkbox', true) ) {
>                         the_post_thumbnail('background');
>                     }
>                     else {}
>                 ?>
>
>             <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
> ```

Comment: FYI, the `showposts` option has been [deprecated since version 2.1](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress documentation [provides an example for this exact situation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail)

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However, I kind of hate opening and closing php tags so lightly. I'll try something to improve this answer.

**Edit**: got it. Please try this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() && get_post_meta($post->ID, 'dbt_checkbox', true) ) {
    echo  '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" >';
    echo  get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'background' );
    echo '</a>';
}
```